# How to test a docker volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to test if I did my docker-compose.yml correctly. The new thing is a volume

```
app:
    image: gitlab-${smt}:5005/smt/my-app:latest
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - $HOME/.docker:/root/.docker
      - /home/profile_x/compose/area:/home/profile_x/compose/area
    environment:
      #not important for my question
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
```

So I added the last volume `/home/profile_x/compose/area` because my goal is to share it from the Docker host to the Docker container, and to write from the container inside the host.

How can I check if the volume is mounted inside the container `app` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can exec a bash shell inside your container and check if the directory exists inside in the path that you've specified.

```
docker exec app /bin/bash -c "[ -d '/home/profile_x/compose/area' ] && echo 'Yes'"
```

This will output **Yes** if the directory exists.

Comment: Wow very nice thank you for the help. I'll keep this little command somewhere because it useful !

Comment: Glad that helped you, please validate the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way is to connect into the docker container.

with:

```
docker ps
```

you get all the running container.

then you have to access the container with:

```
docker exec -it <containername or containerid> bash
```

then cd until you find your folder and look if there are your files.

Comment: I upvote because I could do it like this but the answer of @kstromeiraos is better :) thank you for the help

Comment: how i said its the easiest way :)